# how to set a function output as a signal in pyqt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, signals-slots

I want to display the logged in user `os.getlogin()` displayed in a label widget.

So far I need to set a custom signal and connect it to the label

here is my (not functioning) code, hope you can guide my how to write it properly

```
import sys
import os

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg



class UserTest(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # your code will go here

        user_in_label = qtw.QLabel()

        layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()

        layout.addWidget(user_in_label)

        # funktionen

        self.trigger = qtc.pyqtSignal(str)


        # fire signal to slot
        self.set_signal.connect(user_in_label.setText)


        # your code ends here
        self.show()

    def set_signal(self):
        active_user = os.getlogin()
        self.trigger.emit(active_user)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = UserTest()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`self.set_signal.connect(user_in_label.setText)`
this line is missing an object, do I need to set a new class for this take, seems like nonsense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg


class UserTest(qtw.QWidget):

    trigger = qtc.pyqtSignal(str)                                             # +++

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        user_in_label = qtw.QLabel()

        layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout(self)                                         # + self
        layout.addWidget(user_in_label)
        layout.addWidget(qtw.QPushButton('Click me', clicked=self.set_signal)) # +++

        self.trigger.connect(user_in_label.setText)                            # +++

    def set_signal(self):
        active_user = os.getlogin()
        self.trigger.emit(active_user)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = UserTest()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

---

**Update**

> can you explain why you relocate trigger = qtc.pyqtSignal(str) above init ? and any suggestions how to set active user automatically to the label without the push button?

`trigger` must be a class attribute

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg


class UserTest(qtw.QWidget):

    trigger = qtc.pyqtSignal(str)                                            

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        user_in_label = qtw.QLabel()

        layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout(self)                                         
        layout.addWidget(user_in_label)
#        layout.addWidget(qtw.QPushButton('Click me', clicked=self.set_signal)) 

        self.trigger.connect(user_in_label.setText)                            

        self.set_signal()                                                # +++

    def set_signal(self):
        active_user = os.getlogin()
        self.trigger.emit(active_user)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = UserTest()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thanks a lot! can you explain why you relocate `trigger = qtc.pyqtSignal(str)` above init ? and any suggestions how to set  `active user` automatically to the label without the push button?

Comment: @HoboCoder  see Upade